# Network is Unreachable error from Compute Engine (but fine from local machine)

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am getting an error for my Java-based test code snippet when I run it from a GCE instance (whereas it works fine from my local machine, with the right credentials).

I used to be able to run Pub/Sub code from GCE instances just a few months ago, but seems like no longer. Not sure if this is an ipv4/ipv6 issue, but I can't find any information out there on how to properly configure GCE instances now to work with Pub/Sub.

Not sure if this is the issue, but it seems like i can reach `pubsub.googleapis.com` with `ping`, but not `ping6`:

```
ping pubsub.googleapis.com
PING pubsub.googleapis.com (173.194.196.95) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

vs.

```
ping6 pubsub.googleapis.com
connect: Network is unreachable
```

For what it's worth, here's the full Java stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at PSPublish.main(PSPublish.java:149)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1070)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:707)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:52)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1051)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:63)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:86)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:532)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:482)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:699)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Network is unreachable: pubsub.googleapis.com/2607:f8b0:4001:c03:0:0:0:5f:443
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:694)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:83)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:80)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.connect(SocketUtils.java:80)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:312)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:254)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1366)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.connect(SslHandler.java:716)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$AbstractBufferingHandler.connect(ProtocolNegotiators.java:491)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:136)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$11.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:535)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:474)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: At this stage I can see that the above works on GCE boxes running Ubuntu 19 disco, but not Ubuntu 18 bionic, which was the box I was using originally for legacy reasons. Java environments and everything else seem to be the same though. Still not sure what's the difference...

Answer (score -1):

> I can't find any information out there on how to properly configure GCE instances now to work with Pub/Sub.

There is no Pub/Sub-specific configuration necessary for GCE VMs to talk to the Pub/Sub service. This seems like a networking issue outside the scope of the Pub/Sub service.